# Force UITabBarItem's image to a specific size

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController, initialized by a xib file. all it's view controllers are initialized by a xib file as well.
In apple's HIG it is specified that a High-resolution tab bar icon should be approximately 60x60. I have a set of 52x52 icons, and I used them as the image for the tab items. but for some reason, it displays them as if I'm using a none-high resolution screen - they're off the bounds of the tab bar item, and are pixelized.
How can i set a "fixed" size for the icons so this will be avoided, and how can I, using Interface builder, choose different tab bar images for low-resolution and high-resolution screens?
Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What names are you using for these images?

What you usually have to do is have the standard image named xxxx.png and the high resolution retina display image named xxxx@2x.png

When you use these images in interface builder, use the standard image, the system will look for that filename with "@2x" if it's being executed on an iPhone 4.

Comment: Thank you for that. By using the image I mean, mark the UITabBarItem -> Attributes Inspector -> Bar Item -> image and select the image. EDIT: I see your point. that solved the problem :D tyvm.